# Why is this C++ program giving compile-time error eventhough forward declaration is supplied?

Tags: visual-c++

### Code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyClassOne;

class MyClassTwo
{
    int myInteger;
    float myFloat;

public:
    void SetData(int myIntegerParameter, float myFloatParameter)
    {
        myInteger = myIntegerParameter;
        myFloat = myFloatParameter;
    }
    void Show(MyClassOne myObjectParameter)
    {
        cout<<"MyClassOne..."<<"\n";
        cout<<myObjectParameter.myInteger<<"\n";
        cout<<myObjectParameter.myFloat<<"\n";

        cout<<"MyClassTwo..."<<"\n";
        cout<<myInteger<<"\n";
        cout<<myFloat<<"\n";
    }
};

class MyClassOne
{
    int myInteger;
    float myFloat;

public:
    void SetData(int myIntegerParameter, float myFloatParameter)
    {
        myInteger = myIntegerParameter;
        myFloat = myFloatParameter;
    }
    friend void MyClassTwo :: Show(MyClassOne);
};

int main()
{
    MyClassOne myObjectOne;
    myObjectOne.SetData(10, 10.5);

    MyClassTwo myObjectTwo;
    myObjectTwo.SetData(20, 20.5);

    myObjectTwo.Show(myObjectOne);

    return 0;
}
```

### Error Message:

```
1>friend_function.cpp(22) : error C2027: use of undefined type 'MyClassOne'
1>friend_function.cpp(6) : see declaration of 'MyClassOne'
1>friend_function.cpp(22) : error C2228: left of '.myInteger' must have 

class/struct/union
1>friend_function.cpp(23) : error C2027: use of undefined type 'MyClassOne'
1>friend_function.cpp(6) : see declaration of 'MyClassOne'
1>friend_function.cpp(23) : error C2228: left of '.myFloat' must have 

class/struct/union
1>Generating Code...
1>Build log was saved at "file://Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>Problem_05___Friend_Function - 4 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MyClassTwo::Show` expects a complete definition of `MyClassOne`.

Move the body of the `Show` method to after the definition of `MyClassOne` and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Because you can't use a forward declaration except for providing pointers to objects.

You can do the following instead:

```
//MyClassTwo.h
//declaration in header
void Show(MyClassOne* myObjectParameter);
```

and move the implementation to the cpp file:

```
//MyClassTwo.cpp
void MyClassTwo::Show(MyClassOne* myObjectParameter);
{
    cout<<"MyClassOne..."<<"\n";
    cout<<myObjectParameter->myInteger<<"\n";
    cout<<myObjectParameter->myFloat<<"\n";

    cout<<"MyClassTwo..."<<"\n";
    cout<<myInteger<<"\n";
    cout<<myFloat<<"\n";
}
```

The forward declaration allows you to use pointer as they are all the same size. Using an actual instance would mean you'd have to know the size of the object since it will be pushed on the method's argument stack. But you don't know the size since its declaration wasn't encountered yet. Changing the order of declaration will give an error when declaring the friend.

Separation of implementation and declaration is the way to go.

Comment: Right, because you don't actually have a member to the object in your class.

Answer (score 0):

To access members of a class you need its definition, not just its declaration.

Specifically, you need to have the `MyClassOne` definition above the `MyClassTwo` definition, if you expect `MyClassTwo` to access members of `MyClassOne`.

Also, it would be a good idea to pass `MyClassOne` as a reference to const to the `MyClassTwo::Show()` member function. Therefore, you should redefine it as:

```
void Show(const MyClassOne &myObjectParameter)
```

Comment: Your suggestion is not working. Joachim Pileborg's  suggestion is working well.

Comment: Moving the declarations around would cause errors with the friend declaration.